# Parse JSON from a URL using Volley library in Android

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I need to retrieve some values from JSON url. below code I tried but it but it not giving any error or exception but the values are not got retrieved.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://api.ipstack.com/111.125.204.140? 
access_key=############";

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                JSONObject json = null;
                try {
                    json = new JSONObject(response);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("errror",e.toString());// Not getting any error
                }

                String cityName = json.optString("type");// here iam not getting any value.
                txtJson.setText(cityName);

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        txtJson.setText("That didn't work!");
    }
});

queue.add(stringRequest);
```

JSON structure

```
{
"ip": "134.201.250.155",
"hostname": "134.201.250.155",
"type": "ipv4",
"continent_code": "NA",
  "continent_name": "North America",
"country_code": "US",
"country_name": "United States",
"region_code": "CA",
"region_name": "California",
"city": "Los Angeles",
 "zip": "90013",
 "latitude": 34.0453,
 "longitude": -118.2413
  }
```

I looking for a solution from past 2 weeks. please anyone help me regarding this that will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more specific "does not work for me" is non-helpful statement. Edit your question and be as precise as possible and describe the problem and the error you are facing.

Comment: can you add  error log ?

Comment: I edited and added more information. i didnt got any error while running the application.

Comment: Since you're using `json.optString("type")`, If there is no type key in the response JSON, It won't throw any exception and will return an empty string instead. So, that might be the case here. try to log the response string and see if your response has the type key. Also, If your response is a `JSONObject` why don't you directly use Volley's `JsonObjectRequest`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the JSONobject

```js
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url = "http://api.ipstack.com/111.125.204.140? 
access_key = ############";

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
  new Response.Listener < String > () {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {

      JSONObject json = null;
      try {
        json = new JSONObject(response);
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("errror", e.toString()); // Not getting any error
      }

      /* try this instead */
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
      String cityName = json.getString("city");



    }
  }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
      txtJson.setText("That didn't work!");
    }
  });

queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: could you please tell me what is "jObj" and "data" in the above code

Comment: Oh yes..I missed that....in your case it is "json" as in  JSONObject json = null;
I have edited my answer..check it again

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url ="http://api.ipstack.com/111.125.204.140?
    access_key=############";

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    JSONObject json = null;
                    try {
                        json = new JSONObject(response);
                        if (json.has("type") && !json.isNull("type")) {
                            String cityName = json.getString("type");
                            txtJson.setText(cityName);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("errror",e.toString());// Not getting any error
                    }



                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            txtJson.setText("That didn't work!");
        }
    });

    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Hi Bhavesh. I tried your code its working in android 5.1 emulator but not un android oreo real device. its crashing the app with below error it seems  W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference

Comment: Put your crashlog.